# Indent sub-entries in Index when using IEEEtran style and makeidx

Tags: ieeetran, imakeidx

Simple question: I'm using ieeetran for a very long document that I'm preparing an index for using makeidx. Index entries that include subitems are not indented as expected. I presume this is because ieeetran has their own styling for subsections, but I don't know how to change it just for the index. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a keyword\index{keywords}. But this one is a subkeyword.\index{keywords!subkeyword}  
\index{anotherkeyword!andsubentry}

\section{Index}
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result. Notice how the subentries are not indented. Any ideas on easy ways to fix this? Answers are much appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The class doesn't define a `theindex` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` class (by the way, it's better using this name and not `ieeetran` that works only under Windows) doesn't provide a `theindex` environment.

Here's a modified definition taken from the one in `article.cls` that, however, omits the page break. The commented lines in the code are from the original version, the two added one are marked as such.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{makeidx} \makeindex

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theindex}
 {%
%  \if@twocolumn
%  \@restonecolfalse
%  \else
%  \@restonecoltrue
%  \fi
%  \twocolumn[\section*{\indexname}]%
%  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%          {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  % no page break, continue the columns<-- added
  \section{\indexname}% <----------------- added
  \parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
%  \columnseprule \z@
%   \columnsep 35\p@
  \let\item\@idxitem
 }
 {%
%  \if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi
 }
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}
\newcommand\subitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}
\newcommand\subsubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{30\p@}}
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a keyword\index{keywords}. But this one is a subkeyword.\index{keywords!subkeyword}  
\index{anotherkeyword!andsubentry}

\printindex 

\end{document}
```

[image]